# the desired number of processors are not used

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am running the following fortran code in parallel using openmp, but only one processor is working. I added some of the execution routines like **OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS** and **OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS** to the code to follow the parallel-processing. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
integer a,b,omp_get_num_procs,omp_get_max_threads,
& omp_get_num_threads
open( unit=10 , file='threads' , status='new' )
a=4
call omp_set_num_threads(a)
write(10,*) 'num_proc=',omp_get_num_procs()
write(10,*) 'max_threads=',omp_get_max_threads()
write(10,*) 'num_threads=',omp_get_num_threads()

open( unit=7 , file='result' , status='new' )
!$OMP PARALLEL NUM_THREADS(4)
!$OMP DO DEFAULT(PRIVATE) Shared(rho1,rho2,Vnuc)
 do i = 1 , nx
    do j = 1 , ny
      do k = 1 , nz
         b = omp_get_num_threads()
         write(*,*) 'Hello'
         Write(10,*) 'Hello'
         Write(10,*) b
         write(10,100) omp_in_parallel()
100   format(l2)
...
    enddo
  enddo
enddo
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

or alternatively to the one by one definition of omp parameters in the header I added

```
include 'omp_lib.h'
```

and here is the result:

```
 num_proc=           8
 max_threads=           4
 num_threads=           1
 Hello
       1
 T
 Hello
       1
 F
 Hello
       1
 F
 Hello
       1
 F
 Hello
       1
 F
```

it continues like that. It is running but using only one processor. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Fortran uses implicit typing by default, meaning that undeclared variables/functions starting with `(a-h,o-z)` are real. Your solution is to either add the correct type of the runtime routines, like:

```
integer omp_get_num_threads
```

or, better, add `implicit none` in the beginning to deactivate implicit typing and then include the header file:

```
implicit none
include 'omp_lib.h'
```

EDIT:

that the number of threads outside the parallel region is 1 is fine, however, in the parallel region it should indeed be 4. It could be possible that you're mixing fixed and free format, the former requires the omp directive (e.g. `C$OMP`) at the beginning of a line (on column 1), like so:

```
      program test
      include 'omp_lib.h'
      write(*,*) 'num_proc =    ',omp_get_num_procs()
      write(*,*) 'max_threads = ',omp_get_max_threads()
      write(*,*) 'num_threads = ',omp_get_num_threads()
C$OMP PARALLEL DO
      do i=1,4
        write(*,*) 'num_threads = ',omp_get_num_threads()
      end do
      end
```

If you are using free-form, then you can use `!$OMP` anywhere on a line. The tricky thing is that most compilers allow `!` comment statements even in fixed format source code, but then openmp directives only work when the comment is at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks. The initial problem has been solved by relevant variables type declaration, but now the number of operating threads is **1** and no parallel processing is going on!

Comment: I'd suggest `USE omp_lib` over the include, if the OpenMP implementation supports it.

Comment: If you still have a problem, can you update your question accordingly?

Comment: I am using fixed format (compiled with gfortran 4.6.2), but it does not accept nor **C$OMP** anywhere in the line neither **!$OMP** before column 7. (I mean the compiler returns error on these lines)

Comment: The `C` in `C$OMP` has to be on the very first column, it cannot be anywhere else.

Comment: I put it in the first column, and to examine once I put it somewhere else. But the resulting error was the same. (_unclassifiable OpenMP directive_)

Answer (score 2):

Next to the missing

```
use omp_lib
```

did you complile your program with OpenMP flags? If not, for gfortran it's e.g.

```
-fopenmp
```

Edit: Here is the probably easiest program to test your issue:

```
program prog
  use omp_lib
  implicit none

  integer :: i, tnr

  call omp_set_num_threads( 4 ) !number of threats used in the parallel environment

  !$omp parallel private( i )
    !$omp do
      do i = 1, 20
        tnr = omp_get_thread_num()  ! get threat number
        write( *, * ) 'Thread', tnr, ':',  i
      end do
    !$omp end do
  !$omp end parallel
end program prog
```

Please compile this with e.g. gfortran like:

```
gfortran -fopenmp prog.f90 -o prog
```

It should print you lines like:

```
 Thread           3 :          11
```

Here, 3 is the threat number. If your processor has more than one core and you completely installed your compiler, this should work.

Comment: I use -fopenmp in the compilation line. Using **use omp_lib** causes compilation fault. I have also tried determination of the number of processors using environmental variable **OMP_NUM_THREADS** by _export_ command in the prompt line, but the result is using only one processor.

Comment: If it's still not running, please see my improved answer.

Comment: It did work! First, I put it as prog.f code and it returned 0 for thread numbers, but by putting it as prog.f90 it returned correct numbers. My last programs all have been f77 (.f), now I will change all to f90. Thanks a lot.